# Using switch inside a function, should break be used after a return true?

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

```
function newLinks($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,&$links) {

    switch ($a) {
        case '00':
        $links = "Under Process";
        return true;
           break;


        case '01':
        $links = "Processed";
        return true;
            break;

        case '10':
        $links = "Deleted. Under Process";
        return true;
           break;

        case '11':
        $links = "Deleted. Processed";
            return true;
            break;

        default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is break needed after return true?

Because I do something like this:

```
if ( newLinks($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$links) ) {
    echo $links;
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `$links` as an out parameter? This is PHP, you can return either a string or `false` and the caller can distinguish between them easily. There is no need to `return true`, you can simply `return "Whatever"` and completely remove all references to `$links`.

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I didnt get you. Did u see the way i call the function? I need $link so I can use it in the script below. Do you have another way of doing this?

--Sent from my mobile device

Answer (score 2):

Break is unecessary in this case as the function immediately terminates after returning the value so the break statement would never be reached anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No, you won't need the `break;`, as the function is not executing further after a `return` call.

Answer (score 2):

well you can leave the breaks for clarity to separate the cases. However this can cause bigger issues in the future, because you may not notice the returns.

Why not set a variable in each case, and return once after the switch function is over? In my opinion this will make the code much clearer.

Comment: +1 Multiple exit points increases code complexity.  In this case, it's entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement will just pull it off the function. You don't need the `break` statement in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just like some pals said, `break` isn't need btw